# When Gulp/Babel compiles it doesn't use properly destructuring assignment

Tags: gulp, babeljs, ecmascript-2016

When i compile my JS using Gulp/Babel it doesn't use destructuring assignment.

My Gulp config

```
gulp.task('js', function () {
    return gulp.src(myFiles)
        .pipe(babel({
            presets: ['@babel/env'],
            plugins: ["@babel/plugin-proposal-class-properties"],
        }))
        .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('dist'));
})
```

My code

```
const links = {
        fb: `../../dist/img/facebook.png`,
        li: `../../dist/img/linkedin.png`,
        tw: `../../dist/img/twitter.png`,
    }

    ({ fb, li, tw } = links);
```

The output

```
var links = {
    fb: "../../dist/img/facebook.png",
    li: "../../dist/img/linkedin.png",
    tw: "../../dist/img/twitter.png"
  }((_links = links, fb = _links.fb, li = _links.li, tw = _links.tw, _links));
```

Returns this error

```
app.min.js?ver=5.2.2:14 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'fb' of undefined
```

Did I forget something at my gulp config?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**TL;DR:** Add a semi-colon after you declare `links`, and declare the variables you are destructuring to.

You are taking advantage of [Automatic semicolon insertion](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Lexical_grammar#Automatic_semicolon_insertion), and if you run your code through an [AST Explorer](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/23183795b731fd90d65d3a46f28bb6b4/4c74829e3c1bbacf7e7a61c8dcd5e7edbde8fac5), you'll see your line of `links = { ... }()` is getting parsed as a **CallExpression**, which is *invalid* in this case, hence the error you are receiving.

An example of a *valid* **CallExpression** might be:

```
var a = function(v) { return v }(1); // a === 1

/**
 * Parsed as:
 *
 * VariableDeclaration  VariableDeclarator  CallExpression
 * |                    |                   |
 * v                    v                   v
 * var                  a =                 function(v) { return v }(1)
 */
```

If you add a semicolon, you will see that the `{ ... }` [gets parsed correctly as an **ObjectExpression**](https://astexplorer.net/#/gist/904f85f8f0fc9cb587093e04ffbb5d45/47d19a388cdfa13044d1ea206c753cd92faa22b1).

However, this code will *still* throw a **ReferenceError** due to the variables not being defined and the code being run in [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode).

Its the same reason why this code throws an error:

```js
"use strict";

var obj = { hello: "world" };
hello = obj.hello; // throws a ReferenceError
```

So you need to define the variables, I'm guessing with another `const` declaration.

```js
const links = {
    fb: `../../dist/img/facebook.png`,
    li: `../../dist/img/linkedin.png`,
    tw: `../../dist/img/twitter.png`,
};

const { fb, li, tw } = links;
```

Answer (score -1):

Your code is not valid. Perhaps you want something like this:

```
const links = {
  fb: `../../dist/img/facebook.png`,
  li: `../../dist/img/linkedin.png`,
  tw: `../../dist/img/twitter.png`,
}

const { fb, li, tw } = links
```

I hope this helps.